# Why 404 error occurs even though I have set STATIC_ROOT and urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, django-settings

I don't know why, but I get 404 errors when trying to use static file like this: `{% static 'js/some.js' %}`.

Here's my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("account/", include("account.urls")),
    path("", include("post.urls")),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

And this is my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static/'

# media config 
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR  / 'media/'
```

Thanks!!

**EDIT**

Here's the error I get

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/some.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

And the url you can see here is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
# settings.py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]
```